# Ubuntu 18.04 workspaces and switch between windows

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, 18.04, workspaces

I moved from 17.04 to 18.04 but there is a lot of changes in windows switching and workspaces. On 17.04 I had to use <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key to open all workspaces and then navigate via arrow keys to select. Plus each window was visible in its workplace, it wasn't accessible from other workspaces.

If I have two windows of terminal or code editor, I was able to open them via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> long press and then I had to select the window between. Now it’s like press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, then press down key for selection between same application windows.

It’s extremely annoying, please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible like

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> in US-layout) to switch between windows in same application.

Info found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-switching.html